# Chrome driver has stopped error when running Selenium tests (version 80)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Our chrome instance keeps crashing when running our Selenium tests from a VM that hosts our Jenkins instance and automation containers. It seems to run fine when tried locally (same browser version as the VM). I've been trying to fix this for several weeks now and checked other similar SO posts but to no success so far and am really stuck at this point.

These are the configs we have.

- Chrome Driver version 80.0.3987.106
- Java version 1.8.0_144
- Selenium Chrome driver 3.141.59
- Chrome browser 80.0.3987.149

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized" );
  options.addArguments("disable-infobars" );
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions" );
  options.addArguments("--window-size=1200x600" );
  options.addArguments("--disable-cache" );
  options.addArguments("--disable-application-cache" );
  options.addArguments("--disk-cache-size=0" );
  options.addArguments("--disable-gpu" ); // applicable to windows os only
  options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage" ); // overcome limited resource problems
  options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable" );
  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox" ); // Bypass OS security model
  options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sometimes, its possible to get these kind of errors if Chrome is not restarted/updated properly. Try closing all open Chrome windows and Chrome drivers and running the script. If it still doesnt work, try again after restarting the whole VM.

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your answer. Yes, I have `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` at my `@after` method and all instances of the browser are being closed from the screen.

Comment: Did you to run it without options ? If it crashes without those options the problem is in selenium, if it does not, the problem is of the arguments ( run it just as `driver = new ChromeDriver();` to see if it crashes. If everything works fine without arguments, remove `"--disable-gpu" ` and give it another try ... VM might have some problems with it ( In my opinion, because you said it Windows related thing only ) + try to run it without jenkins as a 1 huge file ( itterative ) to see if that one works fine ... GL in debugging ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll try that on Monday and will come back here to let you know what happens. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the ideal solution but in the end that's what fixed the issue for us.
We added a thread in between tests and after the chrome driver closes, so that it would have some buffer time to breath before reloading and since then it's stopped crashing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though you mentioned about using **Java version 1.8.0_144** but as per your screenshot your effective *Java* version is **1.8.0_77** which is ancient.

[image: javaVersion]

Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

An effective solution would be to upgrade *JDK* to current level of [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that didn't work though, as the update has been done to the most current jdk version but we're still getting the same crashing.